# Normalizate files with join

Tags: bash, awk

I am looking to make tables with 2 or more files of the format:

```
05/2003 3
06/2003 2
07/2003 1
09/2003 2
10/2003 2
11/2003 2
12/2003 1
01/2004 2
02/2004 1
04/2004 2
```

and

```
01/2003 2
02/2003 2
07/2003 1
08/2003 1
09/2003 1
01/2004 2
06/2004 1
09/2004 2
10/2004 1
02/2005 3
```

I need the row that are in a file but not in the other to be inserted with 0 in the field of the file that hasn't the row (it may be done more than 2 files).
The "join" program doesn't do this. If i use the "-a" option it will print all lines but wont preserve the column number. The "-e" option also doesn't help. The output should be in this format:

```
01/2003 0 2 
02/2003 0 2 
05/2003 3 0 
06/2003 0 2 
07/2003 1 1 
08/2003 0 1 
09/2003 2 1 
10/2003 2 0 
11/2003 2 0 
12/2003 1 0 
01/2004 2 2 
02/2004 1 0 
04/2004 2 0 
06/2004 0 1 
09/2004 0 2 
10/2004 0 1 
02/2005 0 3
```

Since now, thank you!

Bonus: If i in the future modify the source of the "join" command to do this, could it be canonized?

Comment: This looks like a problem more suited to SQL "inner join", but a simple one, so may be possible with awk or bash.

Comment: you can concatenate three disjoint sets (file1 only, file1 & file2, file3 only) that can be generated by `join` with some text manipulation to add the missing values but I don't see a trivial solution.  Better revert to full power of `awk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue! with sort assistance...

```
 $ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;f=0;next}
      ($1 in a){f=a[$1]; delete a[$1]}
               {print $1,f,$2; f=0}
            END{for(k in a) print k,a[k],0}' file1 file2 | 
   sort -k1.4n -k1.1,1.2n

01/2003 0 2
02/2003 0 2
05/2003 3 0
06/2003 2 0
07/2003 1 1
08/2003 0 1
09/2003 2 1
10/2003 2 0
11/2003 2 0
12/2003 1 0
01/2004 2 2
02/2004 1 0
04/2004 2 0
06/2004 0 1
09/2004 0 2
10/2004 0 1
02/2005 0 3
```

`awk` to the rescue! again, this should work with arbitrary number of files but I haven't tested for more than 2.

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{c++} {a[$1,c]=$2;keys[$1]} 
          END{for(k in keys) 
                {printf "%s", k; 
                 for(i=1;i<=c;i++) 
                     printf "%s", FS (((k,i) in a)?a[k,i]:0); 
                 print ""}} ' file1 file2 | 
  sort -k1.4n -k1.1,1.2

01/2003 0 2
02/2003 0 2
05/2003 3 0
06/2003 2 0
07/2003 1 1
08/2003 0 1
09/2003 2 1
10/2003 2 0
11/2003 2 0
12/2003 1 0
01/2004 2 2
02/2004 1 0
04/2004 2 0
06/2004 0 1
09/2004 0 2
10/2004 0 1
02/2005 0 3
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a great solution but i cant use it for 3 files even if i use in two and after on the third.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==1{n++}
    {
    a[$1"@"n]=$2;
    b[$1]
    }
END {
    for ( i in b) {
        printf i;
        for ( x=1;x<=n;x++){
             if ( i"@"x in a ){
                printf " "a[i"@"x]
            }
            else{
                printf " 0"
            }
        };
    print ""
    }
}'  file1 file2| sort -n -k2,1 -t/
```

To count the file number counter `n` is used ( `FNR ==1` ).
Array `a` with index as `$1"@"n` is created and assigned value of `$2` ( `a[$1"@"n]=$2` ) and array `b` with index as `$1` is also created.

In the `END`:
Iterate through the array `b` ( `for ( i in b)` ) and for all the files ( `for ( x=1;x<=n;x++)` ) print `$2` ie value in `a` if the `i"@"x` index is in `a` else print 0.

Then sort it based on date ( `sort -n -k2,1 -t/` )